# Gumroad Webhooks Response

Tags: php, wordpress, webhooks

I came across a great checkout solution called Gumroad.  What I am trying to do is use their [webhook functionality](https://gumroad.com/webhooks).

I have a Wordpress site, that when the user buys a product I will generate a user account based on their email.

With webhooks, they send a POST request to my endpoint which I have defined as www.mysite.com/gumroad.  In here is where I want to grab the email address, then I will create the account and generate a password.  What Gumroad expects me to return as stated on the page linked above is :

- → return an HTTP status code of 200
- → have a text/plain content type
- → contain only a URL (in the body)

I have no idea how to do this or what the code *should* look like.

Here is what I have so far and I know this isn't working but I can't figure out what exactly to do.

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: Gumroad Test */

$email = $_POST['email'];

if( isset($email) ){
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    echo "<h1>WEBHOOK WORKING</h1>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get the answer

Answer (score -2):

You only need to echo your full url instead of `"<h1>WEBHOOK WORKING</h1>";`

```
    echo "http://www.example.com/sell";
```